# Salesforce Enable/Disable some portion of email template

Tags: email-template

I have a requirement to make some of the portion of a paragraph in an email template editable and other not. Let's say we have a para of 4 lines, I want to allow user to edit only the second line of it before sending the email.

What I have tried so far:

1. **Using HTML Email Template with letter head :** There we can lock a complete section from editing.
2. **Using contenteditable="false" property :** This again not working in email template.
3. **Custom Email Template** : The entire body is getting locked.

Can someone guide me? Is this achievable in salesforce? If yes, please direct me toward the approach I should consider.
Thanks